# NOT NULL default 1 inserting both 0 and 1

Tags: php, mysql

In MySQL I added a new column to a table...

```
ALTER TABLE `articles` ADD `visible` NOT NULL DEFAULT (1)
```

I used the default as 1 for new articles to be visible and if an article get disabled, it will be updated to 0 meaning it can't be viewed.

Now on new article inserts instead of MySQL inserting the default 1 as defined, it is rather inserting either 0 on some rows and 1 other rows.

I would like to know whats causing this and the possible solution to this issue instead of having to update those rows to 1 manually.

Eg of an insert is...

```
INSERT INTO articles (filename, owner, name, descr, image1, image2, category, added, info_hash, size, numfiles, save_as, news, external, nfo, lang, anon,tube, last_action) VALUES (".sqlesc($fname).", '".$CURUSER['id']."', ".sqlesc($name).", ".sqlesc($descr).", '".$inames[0]."', '".$inames[1]."', '".$catid."', '" . get_date_time() . "', '".$infohash."', '".$articlesize."', '".$filecount."', ".sqlesc($fname).", '".$news."', '".$external."', '".$nfo."', '".$langid."','$anon', ".sqlesc($tube).",'".get_date_time()."')");
```

Then I tried updating it to

```
INSERT INTO articles (filename, owner, name, descr, image1, image2, category, added, info_hash, size, numfiles, save_as, news, external, nfo, lang, visible, anon,tube, last_action) VALUES (".sqlesc($fname).", '".$CURUSER['id']."', ".sqlesc($name).", ".sqlesc($descr).", '".$inames[0]."', '".$inames[1]."', '".$catid."', '" . get_date_time() . "', '".$infohash."', '".$articlesize."', '".$filecount."', ".sqlesc($fname).", '".$news."', '".$external."', '".$nfo."', '".$langid."','$visible', '$anon', ".sqlesc($tube).",'".get_date_time()."')");
```

And

```
$visible = 1;
```

Comment: Show us the INSERTs.

Comment: can't help you unless you show us the insert queries causing this problem.

Comment: These should really be prepared statements. And I assume the `$visible = 1;` comes before the sql statement...

Comment: yes it does but still inserting 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the column that you are inserting to specific type. A generic `ALTER` statement should follow this format.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name column-definition;
```

I'm assuming you only want to have a 1 or a 0 so the following should work:

```
ALTER TABLE `articles` ADD `visible` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add a data type.

You probably want something like:

```
ALTER TABLE `articles` ADD `visible` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
```

If that does not solve it, you are setting default values in your code somewhere.